# How to detect click events in dynamically allocated radiobuttons?

Tags: android

I am currently developing an application for students to see their results, notices, attendance etc. Teachers are also able to take attendance from this app.
I have already completed the portion of getting the students information from the web.

Since the number of students will be variable i have made my content dynamic.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setId(1000 + i);
            //set the color only for the fields in odd places
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.viewSplit));
            }
            row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            //settting height of each row
            int tt = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.height);
            row.setMinimumHeight(tt);
            // part1
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(lp);

            //adding data items in textviews
            int dp = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.student_name);
            TextView textview1 = new TextView(this);
            textview1.setWidth(dp);
            textview1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textview1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textview1.setText(name_of_student.get(i));

            TextView textview2 = new TextView(this);
            textview2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            dp = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.roll_no);
            textview2.setWidth(dp);
            textview2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textview2.setText(roll_no.get(i));

            //if the student is present color is green
            RadioButton radioButtonPresent = new RadioButton(this);
            radioButtonPresent.setHighlightColor(Color.GREEN);
            dp = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.present_abscent);
            radioButtonPresent.setWidth(dp);

            //if the student is absentcolor is red
            RadioButton radioButtonAbscent = new RadioButton(this);
            radioButtonAbscent.setHighlightColor(Color.GREEN);
            dp = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.present_abscent);
            radioButtonAbscent.setWidth(dp);

            row.addView(textview1);
            row.addView(textview2);
            row.addView(radioButtonPresent);
            row.addView(radioButtonAbscent);

            tabLayout.addView(row, i);
```

so i have made two textviews to show the student s name and roll no. and made two radio buttons to select if the student is absent or present.

I can detect click events in the row as i have set id for each row.
But the problem I'm having is how to detect if the user has presses the present radio button or absent radiobutton. and how can i obtain which fields of each table have been clicked.

Alternative solution will also be helpful

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302360/android-how-to-detect-which-tablerow-was-clicked

Comment: i can detect which table row was clicked as i have set id to it. but i need to know which field in that table row was clicked wither present or abscent radiobutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Map` to link students with their ids to the id of the row when you add the row. Then on each radio button define the following:

```
rBtnAbsent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // get the element from the map by the id of the row which will fetch the student as well and do the absent function
        }
    });

rBtnPresent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // get the element from the map by the id of the row which will fetch the student as well and do the present function
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped

Comment: Glad to help. :)